# Kendo pie chart explode function not working

Tags: kendo-ui

Kendo pie chart explode function  not working:

```js
$( e.sender.dataSource.options.data ) //this line become null..
```

following are javascript:

```js
seriesClick: function(e){
                        $( e.sender.dataSource.options.data ).each( function ( i, item ) {
                            if ( item.Description != e.category )
                            {
                                item.Exploded= false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                item.Exploded= true;
                            }
                        } );
                        createChart();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Explode clicked pie chart segment](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/chart/how-to/explode-clicked-pie-segment) demo shows how to do this. Here is the relevant code:

```
    seriesClick: function(e){
      $.each(e.sender.dataSource.view(), function() {
        // Clean up exploded state
        this.explode = false;
      });

      // Disable animations
      e.sender.options.transitions = false;

      // Explode the current slice
      e.dataItem.explode = true;
      e.sender.refresh();
    }
```